# How to convert dozens of fields to Nifi Attributes?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have json with dozens of fields, how can I easily convert it to nifi attribute?

I used EvaluateJsonPath but it is necessary to enter the values ​​one by one.

I will use these attributes in Phoenix DB, When I use ConvertJsontoSQL it doesn't work...

Can you help with this issue?

JoltTransformJSON Sample Content as follows ;

```
{
  "AAAA": "AAAA",
  "BBBB": "BBBB",
  "CCCC": "CCCC",
  "DDDD": "DDDD",
  "EEEE": "EEEE",
  "FFFF": "FFFF",
  "GGGG": "GGGG",
  "HHHH": "HHHH",
  ...
  ...
  ...

}
```

I want to define json fields to nifi Attributes. I don't want to enter one by one with EvaluateJsonPath.

Comment: Are you sure about this solution? You should add all key values to nifi flow attribute?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is such a method. Because I have json with 300 fields, takes a long time...

Comment: @veganzombie, could you show an example of your json? is it complicated or just a plain object with keys?

Comment: you could use script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit :** I found the this Script for ExecuteGroovyScript and handle it.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.*
def flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile == null) {
    return;
}
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def attrs = [:] as Map<String,String>
session.read(flowFile,
    { inputStream ->
        def text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        def obj = slurper.parseText(text)
        obj.each {k,v ->
           attrs[k] = v.toString()
        }
    } as InputStreamCallback)
flowFile = session.putAllAttributes(flowFile, attrs)
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works. Also, I created a custom processor `SplitRecordToAttributes`, https://tonykoval.github.io/nifi-vub-scala-bundle/SplitRecordToAttributes.html

Comment: @tonykoval where can i download this processor?

Comment: https://github.com/tonykoval/nifi-vub-scala-bundle/releases/download/v0.1/nifi-vub-scala-bundle-0.1.nar

Comment: I put nar file under but Error assigning json to attribute. The processor appears. When I enter the attributes values ​​section : errors java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/nifi/json/WriteJsonResult

Comment: I will fix this.

Comment: waiting for news :)

Comment: https://github.com/tonykoval/nifi-vub-scala-bundle/releases/download/v0.2/nifi-vub-scala-bundle-0.2.nar